# Why Admob mediation's ad source is showing not able to optimize?

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have integrated admob mediation as mentioned in admob mediation developing site. But now in mediation the status of every ad networks are showing that "not able to optimize" that means "AdMob was not able to optimize that ad source". So what should I do now to fetch ads for my android application? Point to be noted that my application is based on quiz.

Comment: did you end up figuring out the answer?

Comment: Yes I have not found any solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the network you are using is available for mediation. you can check here https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3245073?hl=en&ref_topic=7383089. Then crosscheck Ad source network credential (ex:secret key,refresh key, orgenizer id,API key whatever required ) from Ad sources which is located at right side of the Mediation Group.